# Use php and simPro API to list customers

Tags: php, api

I login here to an account: https://sandbox.simpro.co

In setup/applications I created a new application. Access Type Direct Access, Signature Method HMAC-SHA1

In the file where "Application URI" points I have this:

```
$headers = array(
    'Host: sandbox.simpro.co',
    'Authorization: OAuth,oauth_version="1.0",
    oauth_nonce="1d0c9d11a944b2439cf867f32d59d21b",
    oauth_timestamp="1355952869",
    oauth_consumer_key="sandbox-simpro-......",
    oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1Access",
    oauth_signature="....."',

'Content-Type: application/json',
'Accept: application/json'

);

$url = 'https://sandbox.simpro.co/api/oauth/access_token.php';

$context = array(
    'http' => array(
        'content' => $content,
        'header' => implode("\r\n", $headers) . "\r\n",
        'method' => $method,
        'timeout' => 10.0,
        'ignore_errors'=>false
    )
);

$response = file_get_contents(
    $url, false,
     stream_context_create($context));
if ($response === false){

    var_dump("<hr><pre>Request Failed", array('url'=>$url, 'method'=>$method, 'headers'=>$headers, 'content'=>$content),'</pre>');

}
```

Nothing works. I know I'm doing everything wrong but on https://api.simpro.co/ there is no PHP example. I just don't understand how to put everything together.

**How do I connect to simPro API with php?**

UPDATE:

This is what I get in on my script:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://sandbox.simpro.co/api/oauth/access_token.php) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 501 Not Implemented in /.../index.php on line 64
string(23) "
Request Failed"
array(4) {
  ["url"]=>
  string(52) "https://sandbox.simpro.co/api/oauth/access_token.php"
  ["method"]=>
  string(4) "post"
  ["headers"]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(23) "Host: sandbox.simpro.co"
    [1]=>
    string(318) "Authorization: OAuth,oauth_version="1.0",
        oauth_nonce="1d0c9d11a944b2439cf867f32d59d21b",
        oauth_timestamp="1355952869",
        oauth_consumer_key="sandbox-simpro-.....",
        oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1Access",
        oauth_signature="...........""
    [2]=>
    string(30) "Content-Type: application/json"
    [3]=>
    string(24) "Accept: application/json"
  }
  ["content"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
string(6) "
```

I understand that I don't describe in the right way my problem, that is because I'm having trouble to understand this API. Then can please give me a link to a php script where this part from https://api.simpro.co/ is used:

Request Token
https://buildname.simpro.co/api/oauth/request_token.php

Authorization
https://buildname.simpro.co/oauth/authorize.php

Access Token
https://buildname.simpro.co/api/oauth/access_token.php

I just want to list the customers with PHP and simPRO.

Comment: "Nothing works" is not a good problem description. You don't ever care saying if `$response` is `false` (and, in such case, what error messages are printed by `var_dump()`). We can't even try ourselves because it's a one-time authorization code with a missing signature.

Comment: Can you use `file_get_contents()` to load anything else (e.g. `http://php.net`)? Have you enabled full error reporting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be worth taking a look at the example code we provide on GitHub:

https://github.com/simPRO-Software/simpro-api-php

This PHP example includes a basic connection to the simPRO API using OAuth and a simple request of data.

Please let me know if you need any further info or assistance.

Comment: can we use simpro api in .net?