# Connecting to SimPro API via Web

Tags: php, oauth

This is a very similar to the question posed at [Use php and simPro API to list customers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24351957/use-php-and-simpro-api-to-list-customers).

The response to that question suggests downloading examples from GitHub. I have downloaded the SimPro examples at GitHub and have them functioning on the commandline.

I want to be able to use a web page as an intermediary between my FileMaker Pro database and the SimPro API. I can pass data to a web page written in PHP. It can convert the data to JSON and form a call to SimPro receive a response and display the success or failure as a web page.

Presently I have my JSON data hardcoded so that I can test the process. When run from  a web browser I don't get a result, though the code works perfectly well running from the command line.

I'm not sure what I need to do make the examples web compatible. Can someone push me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Would be more than happy to help - could you post a snippet of your code - minus the auth info of course - so that I can try to assist?

Do you have your code printing anything else to the browser first - so that you make sure the script is actually executing as it should from the web server side - and have you checked your web server logs for any errors?

In some cases I've seen this is usually due to PHP config (there are separate configs for CLI and CGI in most setups) and can mean whilst libraries are loaded in one environment they may not be available to the other. The web server also usually requires a reload if you have just loaded libraries for use within your script.

Hope that helps.